# How to reduce sencha touch 2 list item height

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How to reduce the height of list item in Sencha touch 2? My list showing large numbers of single word name/value pair. As each item taking extra height, list is becoming too long. So i want to reduce each item height to exact content height. I tried using css like this but no luck. Any help?

var tabPanel=Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {

```
fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
defaults: {
      styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [
    {
        title: 'DETAILS', 
    xtype: 'list',
        cls: 'myList',
        ....
        itemTpl: '<table><tr><td>{fieldName}</td><td>{fieldValue}</td></tr></table>',
    .............



.myList .x-list-item {
       max-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: You can also check this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194848/how-to-set-row-height-sencha-touch-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each list item has a min-height of 2.6em. So, you can reduce that and add a overflow property. Use this:

```
.my-list .x-list-item .x-list-item-label{
     min-height: 0.8em !important;
     overflow : auto;
}
```

And it is not a good practice to use Html tables inside `itemTpl`. Use plain DIV elements with `-webkit-box` CSS3 property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itemHeight config of list. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-itemHeight

in addition to that you can also use CSS like this to control padding:

```
.my-list .x-list-item  .x-list-item-body{
     min-height: 0.5em !important;
     padding-top: 0.3em;
     padding-bottom: 0.3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a property called as

`itemHeight: [*Height of the item you need*],`

i.e

```
itemHeight: 40
```

Read it from the Component's JS file